# Disable SoftKeyboardDetect?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch app which works fine in Chrome. However, when packaged as an Android app using eclipse and the Applaud bundle, it develops a rather odd behaviour, which may be related to SoftKeyboardDetect.

The user may tap a checkbox to enter a comment about information displayed. That unhides a text area where they can write their comment. They then tap a button to continue. The information which was displayed is replaced by new information and again they can check a checkbox to enter a comment. Tapping the continue button causes the checkbox to be unchecked and the textarea to be hidden.

I find that if the user enters a comment on the first information and then taps the continue button, the continue button remains 'depressed' and has to be tapped a second time in order to continue.

I note that hitting the continue button causes the SoftKeyboardDetect event to be fired and wonder if this is what is causing the problem?

If I change the code so that, when the user presses continue, the textarea remains displayed (I.e. Is not hidden), the problem goes away, which leads me to suppose that the phonegap class LinearLayoutSoftKeyboardDetect, which responds to changes in height, is behind the problem. Does anyone know how I can disable that phonegap behaviour?

Comment: Update: as far as I can see from logcat, execution is actually halted at "SoftKeyboardDetect ignore this event", at which point the continue button appears depressed. Only when the continue button is tapped again, does execution continue and the continue button reverts to its unpressed state.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your css

```
* {
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 }
```

src:https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/_bgNkb19C_M

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Agriesean, but I'm afraid it has made no difference. Maybe if you could explain the thinking behind your suggestion, I could follow that up and come across something else.

Comment: I have just add this code in my Android css. Tested with my Android 4.1 and Android 4.0. Unfortunately, they didn't works with IOS.
I do not know what explanation to give you more. 
Do you have show the link?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what on earth was going on. Once I had ensured I could see in the logcat the verbose output regarding SoftKeyboardDetect, I could see that phonegap appeared to be doing something quite sensible.

Every time I tapped a textarea, it would check if the screen area had changed. If it hadn't, then it ignored the event. Same again when the textarea lost the focus, i.e. when I clicked the button to continue.

I eventually discovered that if any textarea in which I had entered text still had the focus just before I clicked the continue button, then things would go wrong, as described above. However, if I ensured I removed the focus from any textareas in which I might have entered any text (by using Sencha's 'blur' method), then everything worked smoothly.

I don't really get it. It may have had something to do with SoftKeyboardDetect, as that was the only thing introduced by phonegap and the app had been running smoothly in Chrome with only Sencha Touch code. However, as mentioned above, SoftKeyboardDetect seemed to be doing quite sensible stuff.